# Multi tables - missing data

Tags: java

Why can't I create multitable which has 2 rows and 3 columns, while I can do the one with 3 rows and 2 columns?

Like in the code below, I cannot display all the slots in the table, as two of them are missing for whatever reason...?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] tab = new int[2][3];
        int number = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tab.length; j++) {
                tab[i][j] = number++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tab.length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("tab[%d][%d]=%d \n", i, j, tab[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `tab.length` is always equal to `2`, because you instantiated your array with `new int[2][3]`. Use `tab[i].length` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`tab.length` will give you the length of first dimension. You should use `tab[i].length` like below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] tab = new int[2][3];
    int number = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
            tab[i][j] = number++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("tab[%d][%d]=%d \n", i, j, tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In Java, multidimentional arrays don't actually exist. Instead, an `int[][]` is [just an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-10.html) with `int[]`.

For example, it is perfectly fine to just do this:

```java
tab[1] = new int[7];
```

Now the array is not a matrix anymore, as the separate arrays each have [different sizes](https://ideone.com/pjvK9P). This is called a *jagged* array. The 'multidimensional' array now looks like this:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In your case, `tab.length` refers to the length of the outside array. To get the length of each subarray, use `tab[i]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put the length of column based of specific row e.i **tab[row].length** in *inner loop*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int row = 3;  //setting row here
        int col = 4;  // setting column here
        
        int[][] tab = new int[row][col];
        int number = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
                tab[i][j] = number++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("tab[%d][%d]=%d \n", i, j, tab[i][j]);;
            }
            
        }
    }
```